# Autosized textarea clipping issue with IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to implement a simple auto sized textarea component with VueJS but I'm facing an issue with IE.

On this browser only, we can feel the height calculation. The size of the textarea changes twice and we can easily see the following content moving.

Here's how I'm doing it :

Each time the value changes, I'm calling the following `resizeTextarea` method :

```
resizeTextarea: function() {
  // Set the height to auto to have a correct scrollHeight
  this.textareaStyle.height = 'auto';
  // Wait for the next tick to be sure that the heigh is set to 'auto'
  this.$nextTick(this.setHeight);
},
```

With the referenced `setHeight` method :

```
setHeight: function() {
  //IE COMPATIBILITY this.textareaStyle.height = `${this.$refs.input.scrollHeight}px`;
  this.textareaStyle.height = ''.concat(this.$refs.input.scrollHeight, 'px');
},
```

As you can see, the process is quite simple :

- Setting the textarea's height to `auto`;
- After the value is updated, setting the height to the component's `scrollHeight`.

However, I have to wait the next tick to set the height and I'm guessing that this causes the clip with IE.

In my HTML template, I'm binding the `textareaStyle` data to the textarea component and I'm referencing it via a ref :

```
<textarea 
  v-model="message" 
  ref="input"    
  :style="textareaStyle"
  ></textarea>
```

You can found a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ThomasFerro/1fo0wy9s/), please run it on IE and another browser to see the difference.

Notes :

- I'm not using ES' syntax to ensure IE compatibility;
- I've already tried to use the [autosize package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autosize) but the results are the same.

This issue may be due (and most certainly is) to my implementation of the auto sized textarea, so I'll consider this issue closed if the current system get fixed or if another solution (working in every modern browsers + IE 11) is found.

Comment: Your example works as expected for me in IE11, or the problem is just not obvious to me.

Comment: It happens pretty fast but on IE11 you should be able to see the `textarea` taking the size of two lines and then only resize to fit the content each time you write something.